# Relation between positive roots of $E_8$ and $\mathbb{F}_2^8 \setminus \{0\}$

Tags: lattices, quadratic-forms, characteristic-p, euclidean-lattices

There exists an explicit bijection (due to Cayley, that has built up a very nice table to describe this) between the positive roots of the lattice $E_7$ and $\mathbb{F}_2^6 \setminus \{0\}$ (where $\mathbb{F}_2$ is the field with two elements. Btw, this also preserves orthogonality. There is also a relation between $E_8$ and $\mathbb{F}_2^8 \setminus \{0\}$. Is there an  explicit description of the features of this relation in the literature?

Comment: I don't understand: $E_8$ has 120 positive roots, but $2^8-1=255$.

Comment: Yes, you are right, I am quite confused. The reduction modulo 2 of $E_8$ must have a quadratic form with values in $\mathbb{F}_2$ hence there is a non trivial map from $W(E_8)$ to the orthogonal group $O^+(8,\mathbb{F}_2)$ (with kernel $\pm 1$). So what is the relation with $\mathbb{F}_2^8$?

Comment: The positive roots correspond to vectors with $q=1$ for the induced quadratic form. This is described for instance in Exercise 1 of Bourbaki *Lie groups and Lie algebras*, ch. VI, §4.

Comment: A construction of the E8 root system is described here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E8_(mathematics)#E8_root_system

Comment: I have edited the question to make a better link with the answers.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let $L$ denote the root lattice of $E_8$. The group $W(E_8)$ acts (linearly) on $L/2L \cong \mathbb{F}_2^8$, and hence as a permutation of $2^8=256$ elements. This permutation action has the following three orbits:

1. $\{0\}$, an orbit of size 1.
2. The classes represented by roots, an orbit of size 120. There are 240 roots in $L$, but each root is equivalent to its negative mod $2L$. In particular, each element of this orbit is represented by a unique positive root.
3. The *frames*, an orbit of size 135. The $E_8$ lattice has $240\cdot9$ vectors of length$^2=4$, and each one is congruent to 16 such vectors (including itself). For example, in a rather standard basis (in which $E_8 \supset D_8 \subset \mathbb{Z}^8$), the vector $(2,0^7)$ is congruent to the 16 vectors $(0^a, \pm 2, 0^{7-a})$.

Incidentally, the stabilizer of a root is $W(E_7)$, whereas the stabilizer of a frame is $W(D_8)$. You do indeed find that $\#W(E_8) = 120\cdot \#W(E_7) = 135 \cdot \#W(D_8)$.

For further details, see for example Section 8.1.2 of [Berkeley lectures on Lie and quantum groups](http://categorified.net/LieQuantumGroups.pdf). (That section is based on lectures by Richard Borcherds, an expert in lattices.)